# RestKit relationships not mapping when manually mapping JSON object

Tags: ios, json, swift, restkit

I am following some suggested posts on how to map incoming JSON data directly using RKMapperOperation. My entity object is being created in the data store, but without the proper relationships. Interestingly, if I create an object directly using the Core Data methods after I've already mapping incoming JSON (via websockets), the operation seems to "flesh" out my relationships in the incorrect entity.

To sum the order:

1. JSON data comes into app through a websocket connection
2. I map it using the below code, but the relationships aren't mapped
3. I save some other record in the same entity using a locally created (not RestKit) object with Core Data.
4. My object mapped from JSON now has its relationships attached!

Here is the JSON data:

```
{
    "checkin": {
        "session_id": 1,
        "attendee_id": 70,
        "source": "list",
        "created_at": "2015-03-26 11:53:08",
        "cache_id": "9234d700852df5c7402b87adf6ecfc19",
        "checkout": "0",
        "updated_at": "2015-03-27 03:53:09",
        "id": 359
    }
}
```

Here is my mapping function

```
func mapEntityFromJson(JSONString: String, key: String, mapping: RKEntityMapping!) -> NSManagedObject? {
    let MIMEType = "application/json"
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let data = JSONString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let jsonDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
    let parsedData: AnyObject! = RKMIMETypeSerialization.objectFromData(data, MIMEType: MIMEType, error: &error)
    if (parsedData == nil && error != nil) {
        // Parser error...
        return nil
    }

    let mappingsDictionary = [ key: mapping ]

    let mappingDS = RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource(managedObjectContext: self.objectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext, cache: self.objectStore.managedObjectCache)

    let mapper = RKMapperOperation(representation: parsedData, mappingsDictionary: mappingsDictionary)
    mapper.mappingOperationDataSource = mappingDS
    var mappingError: NSError? = nil
    let isMapped = mapper.execute(&mappingError)
    if (isMapped && mappingError == nil) {
        // Trying to save twice per some other example
        self.objectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext.save(&error)
        self.objectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext.saveToPersistentStore(&error)
        let result = mapper.mappingResult.firstObject() as NSManagedObject
                    return result
    }
    return nil
}
```

Here is the relationship mapping I'm passing to this function:

```
func checkinMapping() -> RKEntityMapping {
    let checkinMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Checkin", inManagedObjectStore: objectStore)
    let checkinDictionary = ["source": "source", "checkout": "checkout", "cache_id": "cacheId", "attendee_id": "attendeeId", "session_id": "sessionId"]

    checkinMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(baseRecordDictionary)
    checkinMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(checkinDictionary)
    checkinMapping.addConnectionForRelationship("attendee", connectedBy: ["attendeeId": "id"])
    checkinMapping.addConnectionForRelationship("session", connectedBy: ["sessionId": "id"])
    checkinMapping.identificationAttributes = ["cacheId"]
    checkinMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = true

    return checkinMapping
}
```

Here is how the function gets called when the websocket subscription is notified:

```
let jsonString = "<the JSON data per above>"
let mappingResult = self.mapEntityFromJson(jsonString, key: "checkin", mapping: self.checkinMapping())
```

The `attendee_id` and `session_id` values should be establishing a relationship with `Attendee` and `Session` entities, but when I look at the sqlite data underlying Core Data the relationship columns are blank even though the incoming `attendeeId` and `sessionId` fields get mapped. Once I make the other save locally then those relationship columns get mapped.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
I should add that when a checkin is mapped from a full RestKit call like .getObject or as the result of .postObject then the mapping works with no issues. It is only in the manual mapping I have here that it seems to fall apart.

Comment: Show the JSON. Is there a reason you're using the operation instead of an object manager? The question also doesn't show the link between the two pieces of code you show...

Comment: I have expanded the question with the JSON data and how the function calls are used.

Comment: So it seems your problem is really that you want stub objects to be created, if the objects don't already exist, for the ids so you can connect the relationships and then fill in the details later?

Comment: Actually, the attendee object and session object referred to by the attendee_id and session_id respectively will always exist prior to the checkin. Those records always exist before the object comes in over web sockets. I'll explore sending them in the JSON anyway but it will more than double the data size coming through which just seems inefficient considering I already have the records locally.

Comment: You don't need to send them nested if you already have them. Are you sure they're persisted to disk before you run this part?

Comment: The existing attendee and session records are definitely persisted to disk. They came through as part of the login to the app.

Comment: Not sure if this gives a clue, but creating a record locally only "fixes" the last record that came through the websocket mechanism. So if I have several records with disconnected relationships and then create a Checkin locally, only the last disconnected record gets fixed.

Comment: These are 1-to-many relationships, and things are being disconnected when a new thing is added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74191/discussion-between-davidethell-and-wain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution which involved much help from @wain and a key point from another post about needing to make the operationQueue wait until all operations are finished or else the mapping process hadn't finished mapping the relationships. So my NSManagedObject was returning with no relationships connected. The combination of a private child context for proper concurrency and saving of data along with the waiting issue fixed the problem. Here is the final mapping code:

```
func mapEntityFromJson(JSONString: String, key: String, mapping: RKEntityMapping!) -> NSManagedObject? {
    let MIMEType = "application/json"
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let data = JSONString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    let jsonDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
    let parsedData: AnyObject! = RKMIMETypeSerialization.objectFromData(data, MIMEType: MIMEType, error: &error)
    if (parsedData == nil && error != nil) {
        // Parser error...
        return nil
    }

    let mapperContext = self.objectStore.newChildManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType, tracksChanges: true)

    let mappingsDictionary = [ key: mapping ]

    let mappingDS = RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource(managedObjectContext: mapperContext, cache: self.objectStore.managedObjectCache)
    var mappingResult: RKMappingResult? = nil
    var result: NSManagedObject? = nil

    let mapper = RKMapperOperation(representation: parsedData, mappingsDictionary: mappingsDictionary)
    mappingDS.operationQueue = self.operationQueue
    mappingDS.parentOperation = mapper
    mapper.mappingOperationDataSource = mappingDS
    var mappingError: NSError? = nil
    let isMapped = mapper.execute(&mappingError)
    // Necessary to wait for relationships to map.
    if self.operationQueue!.operationCount > 0 {
        self.operationQueue!.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
    }
    if (isMapped && mappingError == nil) {
        mapperContext.saveToPersistentStore(&error)
        mappingResult = mapper.mappingResult
    }

    if mappingResult != nil {
        result = mappingResult!.firstObject() as? NSManagedObject
    }

    return result
}
```

For now we're leaving it with the in-memory cache and don't see the duplicates issue others reported.